# Registration on Success Page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php, checkout, register

I want to add the possibility to ask the guest customer to create an account on the success page, after the order has been received in magento.

[image]

**Update:** I think this function name is Register after Checkout.

Comment: robert do you tried some thing ?

Comment: I don't know from where I need to start, for that I post it here, meybe is someone much smarter than me :)

Comment: Maybe if I try to add registration form there? My idea is to hide all the register fields and leave only the password, but how I can complete the email, firstname, lastname for example with the corect data to pass the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your screenshot, you are using custom theme. That’s why you need to localize this page (success page) first. Make sure that it has the call `getChildHtml`. If there is not such a call, then you should add it for the block that we gonna create. I’ve taken rwd theme as basis.

If you don’t have a module for customizations, then create it. In my case, this is `Test_Module`. There are plenty of articles in the web, where you could find how to create modules.

We need one new block `Test_Module_Block_Checkout_Success_Register` where we place the main logic that could be expanded later.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: usr
 * Date: 6/2/16
 * Time: 10:12 AM
 */

class Test_Module_Block_Checkout_Success_Register extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    /**
     * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order|null
     */
    protected $order;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
     * @return Test_Module_Block_Checkout_Success_Register
     */
    public function setOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order|null
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare customer data for the register form
     *
     * @return mixed|Varien_Object
     */
    public function updateFormData()
    {
        $data = $this->getData('form_data');
        if (is_null($data)) {

            /** @var array $formData */
            $formData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerFormData(true);

            $order = $this->getOrder();
            $customerData = [
                'email' => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
                'firstname' => $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
                'lastname' => $order->getCustomerLastname(),
                'city' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity(),
                'country' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCountry(),
                'region_id' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getRegionId(),
            ];

            $data = new Varien_Object();
            if ($formData) {
                $data->addData($formData);
                $data->setCustomerData(1);
            }
            $data->addData($customerData);

            if (isset($data['region_id'])) {
                $data['region_id'] = (int)$data['region_id'];
            }

            $this->setData('form_data', $data);
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare block data:
     * > Get order id
     * > load order
     * > set data to the block
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        parent::_beforeToHtml();

        /** @var Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success|null $successBlock */
        $successBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.success');
        if (!$successBlock) {
            return $this;
        }

        /** @var string $orderId order Increment Id here (not the real id!) */
        $orderId = $successBlock->getOrderId();
        /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

        $guest = $order->getCustomerIsGuest();
        if (!$guest) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->setOrder($order);
        $this->updateFormData();

        return $this;
    }
}

?>
```

In this block we are using method `_beforeTOHtml` where the check for block drawing is held and the order with all required customers’ information is loaded. If you are a perfectionist, you can separate this part for different methods, but the overall way is clear. We are receiving the order `icrement_id` from the parental block where it should be.

Note! If your theme is using another system of order receiving, simple replace it in the block with your own.

Then, we need a copy of `customer/form/register.phtml` template that we will edit to get the desired result. Copy the file to the templates folder of your module. In my case this is `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/test/customer/form/register.phtml`. Next, delete all the unnecessary information from the template, but leave all the input fields and widget calls. This is my template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra') ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
    <!--        Hide customer main data fields-->
    <div class="fieldset" hidden="hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>"/>
        <ul class="form-list" hidden="hidden">
            <li class="fields">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address"
                           value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>"
                           title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>"
                           class="input-text validate-email required-entry"/>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
            <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li><?php echo $_dob->setDate($this->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php $_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat') ?>
            <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li><?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
            <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li><?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php if ($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
        <!--        Hide address fields-->
        <div class="fieldset" hidden="hidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1"/>

            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Address Information') ?></h2>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>

                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="company" id="company"
                                   value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>"
                                   title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>"
                                   class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>

                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone"
                                   value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>"
                                   title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>"
                                   class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="street[]"
                               value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet(1)) ?>"
                               title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1"
                               class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                    <li class="wide">
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="street[]"
                                   value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet($_i)) ?>"
                                   title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>"
                                   id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>"
                                   class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endfor; ?>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>

                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="city"
                                   value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>"
                                   title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>"
                                   class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>"
                                   id="city"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>
                        </label>

                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>"
                                    class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option
                                    value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                //<![CDATA[
                                $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', "<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>");
                                //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="region" name="region"
                                   value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getRegion()) ?>"
                                   title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>"
                                   class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>"
                                   style="display:none;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>

                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="postcode"
                                   value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>"
                                   title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip"
                                   class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>

                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1"/>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Save Your Information For Next Time!') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>"
                               class="input-text required-entry validate-password"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>
                    </label>

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>"
                               id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
            <?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
                <li class="control">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed"
                               title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1"
                               id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>
                               class="checkbox"/>
                    </div>
                    <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
                    <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') ?>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Register') ?>" class="button">
            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
    <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
    new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'zip');
    <?php endif; ?>
    //]]>
</script>
```

For the fieldsets that shouldn’t be displayed, but will be filled from the block by default, we should set the attribute `hidden="hidden"`. If you delete them completely, the registration won’t be able to complete. Only the fieldset with a password and field with subscription stay visible.

Thus, we are using standard registration block for this form, then we need one intermediate template for our block, where this standard block with our template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/test/checkout/register.phtml` will be called.

```
<?php
if (!$this->getOrder()) {
    return;
}
$this->getChild('customer_form_register')->setData('form_data', $this->getData('form_data'));
echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_register');
?>
```

Finally, we need a layout, where we mark all changes in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/test.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="test/checkout_success_register" name="checkout.success.register.form" template="test/checkout/register.phtml">
                <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="test/customer/form/register.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                        <label>Form Fields Before</label>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

The result in the rwd theme should be the following:

[image]

All hidden fields are here with the values from the order:

[image]

Registration completed successfully:

[image]

Pay attention, that this is only a model, that you should customize to suit your theme and correct according to the desired result.

I hope this information will be useful. If you have any question – feel free to ask them.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much I made the same like you, I put your code in my extension in the RWD theme, I use this extension, https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/28996/s/enhanced-order-success-page/ the problem is after I press on Register button I am redirect to customer/account/create/. you have any idea?

Comment: I made some research there, I think the problem is that the extension not get the required fields.     <?php if ($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?> I think here is a problem too. and the street adress and state option value is blank, can you tell me please how we can take the street and region value

Comment: So the only problems is with the zip and street values, you have any idea what is wrong in your code?

Comment: @RobertD if your check `$this->getShowAddressFields()` returns false, then there is no need in fields. But it if you want to display them, you can simply remove it from the template. Most probably, the reason for the redirect is something different, may be in other module. It is difficult to suggest a solution without a complete project but you'd better start with the template and the appropiate controller check.

Comment: same issue here. When I click on Register button then its redirect to customer/account/create/. @Robert have you got the solutions? if yes then can you please update here.

Comment: Got the issue behind that. In new version of Magento they added form key validations so you have to pass form key from phtml file. I added it and now its working fine.